# Help with a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Can anyone give (i) an example with the properties indicated or (ii) show
that there is no example that has the properties indicated for the following case.

A (single) convergent sequence $a_n$ with limit $l$ for which $a_n=l$ for infinitely many values of $n$, and $a_n\neq l$ for infinitely many values of $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a_{2n}=0$, $a_{2n+1}=n^{-1}$.

Comment: That works great! I was trying to think of an $a_n$ on its own, but sure making it vary for odd and even $n$'s works great. Thanks!